# Poco ODBC library undefined reference error

Tags: c++, odbc, poco-libraries

I am in process to build a program that establish connectivity with MySQL database using ODBC. I am using Poco-Data-ODBC library for the same. I am getting the following error :

```
D:\Hardware\Windows\PocoODBC/PocoODBC.cpp:27: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN4Poco4Data4ODBC9Connector17registerConnectorEv'
D:\Hardware\Windows\PocoODBC/PocoODBC.cpp:34: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN4Poco4Data4ODBC9Connector19unregisterConnectorEv'
D:\Hardware\Windows\PocoODBC/PocoODBC.cpp:41: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN4Poco4Data4ODBC9Connector19unregisterConnectorEv'
```

Build Command :

```
g++     -o dist/Debug/Msys64_MinGW-w64_7.3.0-Windows/pocoodbc build/Debug/Msys64_MinGW-w64_7.3.0-Windows/PocoODBC.o build/Debug/Msys64_MinGW-w64_7.3.0-Windows/main.o
-L/C/msys64/mingw64/bin -L/C/Program\ Files/MySQL/Connector.ODBC\ 5.3 -lodbc32 -lPocoDataODBC -lws2_32 -lPocoFoundation -lPocoData
```

Linked Libraries :

> -lodbc32
>
> -lPocoDataODBC
>
> -lws2_32
>
> -lPocoFoundation
>
> -lPocoData

Source Code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <windows.h>

#define POCO_WIN32_UTF8

#include <Poco/Event.h>
#include <Poco/Data/Data.h>
#include <Poco/Data/Session.h>
#include <Poco/Data/RecordSet.h>
#include <Poco/Data/ODBC/Connector.h>

Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::registerConnector();
    //const std::string ConnectionString("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=test; USER=venu; PASSWORD=venu; OPTION=3;");
    const std::string ConnectionString("Dsn=HamsterPro20 ANSI; USER=root; PASSWORD=tantra@123; OPTION=3;");
    Poco::Data::Session session("ODBC", ConnectionString);
    if(not session.isConnected())
    {
        std::cout << "Session connection failed" << std::endl;
        Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::unregisterConnector();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Session connection success" << std::endl;
        session.close();
        Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::unregisterConnector();
        return true;
    }
```

- Platform: x64
- OS: Windows 10 Pro
- Development Environment: Msys64 (mingw-w64 )
- IDE: Netbeans
- Compiler: mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc 7.3.0-2

Comment: Did you define `Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::unregisterConnector();`? 
Or is it a library function?

Comment: Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::unregisterConnector() is a library function.             Link ->      https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Data.ODBC.Connector.html

Answer (score 1):

I asked for the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599269), but I've found the solution myself (also published in my question):

When compiling files for Data/ODBC I got some warnings, something like

`redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored`

for files `Data\ODBC\src\Extractor.cpp` and `Data\ODBC\src\Preparator.cpp`.

Regardless these warnings, the files are compiled. But when the library is generated it lacks of entry points, as exposed in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599269).

The solution is to add `#include "Poco/Foundation.h"` at the beginning of `Data\ODBC\src\Extractor.cpp` and `Data\ODBC\src\Preparator.cpp`.

I could guess this from this [poco issue](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/2302).