# POCO libraries: MinGW (MSYS2) compilation has generated libPocoDataODBC.dll with missing entry points (Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::registerConnector)

Tags: dll, cmake, odbc, mingw-w64, poco-libraries

I have succeeded compiling POCO libraries with MinGW64 (MSYS2).
To build it, I installed Windows SDK and added to the PATH environment the path to `mc.exe`, so I executed:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake
# Get POCO
git clone -b master https://github.com/pocoproject/poco.git
# set Windows SDK to the PATH
export PATH="/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/bin/10.0.18362.0/x64:$PATH"
# Prepare compilation
cd poco
/mingw64/bin/cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
# Compile
make
```

The compilation succeeded and libraries were generated.

Then, in the code of my c++ project, I use POCO::Data::ODBC and register it with:

```
Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::registerConnector();
```

The application compiles, but there is a linker error:

```
undefined reference to `Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::registerConnector()'
```

Inspecting the library libPocoDataODBC.dll with dllexp.exe I can confirm there is no entry point defined  for Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::registerConnector()

Any idea of the reason of this lack of entry points in the library?
My code accesses other POCO libraries with no problem. IT only affects Poco::Data::ODBC.

**Note**: I'm linking the librares with parameters
`-lPocoDataODBC -lPocoData -lPocoNet -lPocoJSON -lPocoUtil -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNetSSL -lPocoXML`

I can see a similar question at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50168733/12288398) but with no answer...

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the solution. I leave it here just in case someone finds it useful.

There are some warnings compiling files for Data/ODBC: something like

`redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored`

for files `Data\ODBC\src\Extractor.cpp` and `Data\ODBC\src\Preparator.cpp`.

Regardless these warnings, the files are compiled. But when the library is generated it lacks of entry points, as exposed in my question.

The solution is to add `#include "Poco/Foundation.h"` at the beginning of `Data\ODBC\src\Extractor.cpp` and `Data\ODBC\src\Preparator.cpp`.

I could guess this from this [poco issue](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/2302).